# Avoiding using isset() on the form?

Tags: php, forms

When you have many inputs (select/textarea/input), it will look real messy when you include `isset()`

For example:

```
<input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" 
  value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : "";?>">
```

In there alternative way so it will look tidy and maintainable?

I am using MVC Framework if that help.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: You're not even `echo`ing it. Dirty hack solution is `value="<?=$_POST['firstname'];?>"` (you didn't hear it from me)

Comment: @Brad I have wrote my own, it is similar to codeigniter style.

Comment: @Mihail, That's a terrible idea, and will leave you with null reference exceptions.

Comment: @Mikhail sorry, I've fixed my question. By the way `<?=` is not recommended.

Comment: I know! I said you didn't hear it from me!

Comment: @user791022 not sure where you heard that <?= is not recommended, but its simply not true. it's integral to php enough in the upcoming version <?= will be available regardless of directive settings.

Comment: Why would a post-submitted form have a not set value? Doesn't it submit as `&firstname=&lastname` etc.? this would make it a set empty string.

Comment: @Mikhail presumably the same output is being used for the postback form in the case of an error as is for the initial view of the form before any postback.

Comment: @user791022 With PHP5.4 `<?= $fo; ?>` is always available and "re-recommended" again. Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your own function that would fill values:

```
function get_post( $key, $default = ''){
    if( isset( $_POST[$key])){
       return htmlspecialchars( $_POST[$key]);
    }
    return htmlspecialchars( $default);
}
```

And use it as:

```
<input ... value="<?php echo get_post( 'firstname', 'Your name'); ?>" />
```

Or anyway that it'd be incorporated into your framework.

If you need more complete keys you could do it like this:

```
function get_post( ){
    $args = func_get_args();
    if( count( $args) < 2){
       // Wrong usage, throw an exception
    }
    $default = array_pop( $args);

    $progress = $_POST;
    while( $key = array_shift( $args)){
        if( !is_array( $progress) || !isset( $progress[$key])){
           $progress = $default;
           break;
        }
        $progress = $progress[$key];
    }
    return htmlspecialchars( $progress);
}

echo get_post( 'my', 'multiple', 'keys', 'default');
```

#### Preparing variables

You may also take advantage of php [`array operator+`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) and set all variables:

```
<?php

$myList = array( 'name' => 'Your name', 'another' => 'Another');
$values = $_POST + $myList;
```

And than just:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $values['name']); ?>
```

Comment: I would suggest returning the value instead of printing it. This way you can use this function somewhere else.

Comment: @Mikhail Yeah, me either I was using `g_post`, `g_get` and `g_array` (this like getters) at the time, this is just custom version.

Comment: this is quite useless function. What if you need to print data from the db? use print_db() then?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel if he doesn't use form elements that support autofilling from `$_POST`  he need to fill them by hand, I'd personally go for functions lie `get_post()` but the idea of the function was to do it with the least code in view template. Other approach, not "the perfect solution"

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel damn it you're right, changed to `get...`, and I quite like it this way... Any constructive critics?

Comment: I have a habit of centralized data processing. With Post it's especially easy. Like I said in my answer, I believe that by the time variable have to be printed out from the template - it has to be initialized with the right value. So, basically I have an empty  `$FORM` array which members represents form values, and can be filled with either POST or db data along with applying htmlspecialchars on them. So, in the template I am using only `<?=$FORM['firstname'] ?>`

Answer (score 3):

You could pre-parse all variables that you're using:

```
<?php
$v_list = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'birthdate');
$v_vals = array();
foreach ($v_list as $v) {
    if (isset($_POST[$v])) $v_vals[$v] = $_POST[$v];
    else $v_vals[$v] = "";
}
?>

<input ... value="<?php echo $v_vals['firstname']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If the behavior is always the same, define a short-named function:

```
function val ($variable, $default)
{
  if isset($variable)
      return $variable;
  else
     return $default;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
<input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" 
  value="<?= val(@$_POST['firstname'],"")?>">
```

Also note that the final ";" is not needed if you have nothing else within the

Finally, the `<?=` is a shortcut for `<?` echo, but it only works with short tags (`<?`) and not with `<?php`.

It's not awesome but a lot briefer.

Comment: Your function should either return $default or not accept a $default parameter

Comment: Downvoting without an explanation is very unconstructive. If you dislike something about this solution, please clarify so maybe it can be amended.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped the gun. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Won't this throw a warning if 'firstname' is not set in the $_POST array?

Comment: Nice catch, it may, I modified so the warning gets eaten.

Comment: You really shouldn't use the error suppression operator. Ever. I wish PHP would remove it altogether... Won't downvote for now, but definitely not a good idea IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using MVC, you should avoid polling the supervariables in the view. Also, array_key_exists is superior to isset for this sort of thing.

So, in the controller you should have:

```
$myview->firstname = array_key_exists( 'firstname', $_POST ) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
```

and in the view

```
<input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="<?= $this->firstname ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Like with many other concepts, PHP users take this one wrong.

When a user gets "Undefined variable" message, a usual attitude towards it: "What a noisy thing! Is there a *pious* method to get rid of it?"
"Sure thing!" - comes along a fellow PHP user with some code, never busying himself with a question: what is that error message? Why I am getting it? Should I correct it?

So, here comes isset or some wrapper for isset.

But if you care to think of the meaning of the error message, it become clear that a programmer just have to always know, which variables he have and what are values.

And "Undefined variable" message is merely a hint: you have no idea what variable you are using and if it ever exists!

So, the proper solution would be to define a variable which you are going to use in the form. For the empty one you have to define an empty one. You don't usually need to check every one, though. One condition is enough.

So, *the true right thing* would be *to define* every variable you are going to use in the *template* before loading it.

Not to mention that you shouldn't post raw data in a value attribute, but always pass it through htmlspecialchars()

Answer (score -2):

Accessing an undefined variable throws an `E_NOTICE`. `E_NOTICE`s can be more or less ignored (otherwise they'd be `E_WARNING`s or `E_ERROR`s), so set `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` and echo those variables without checking their existence first.

Alternatively, instead of typing `isset` for every one, define a function like so:

```
<?php
function echoifset(&$var) {
    if( isset($var)) echo $var;
}
?>
```

Then you can just call `<?php echoifset($_POST['firstname']); ?>` and it does the same as all your current checks.

Comment: Even if you ignore the E_NOTICE via error_reporting, the notices WILL show up in your logs, resulting in a lot of useless fluff. Performing a simple validation check, especially in MVC, is far easier than hacking the php config.

Comment: I've never seen a single E_NOTICE in my error logs, even though I know I'm ignoring plenty of them.

Comment: Downvoted. You should **never** ignore notices. Not to mention that you should **never** print from inside a function (return it instead).